# Многопоточность

Tags: java, многопоточность

Здравствуйте, помогите, пожалуйста с заданием. Программа блочится, когда автобусы меняются пассажирами. По заданию : если два автобуса на одной и той же остановке, то пассажиры могут поменяться автобусами.
Вот класс `Bus` :

```
public class Bus implements Runnable {
    private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private Exchanger < Passengers > exchanger;
    private Passengers passengers;
    private ArrayList < BusStation > busStations;
    private int number;
    private BeforeState beforeState = new BeforeState();
    private AfterState afterState = new AfterState();

    public Bus(ArrayList busStations, int number, Passengers passengers, Exchanger < Passengers > exchanger) {
        this.busStations = busStations;
        this.number = number;
        this.passengers = passengers;
        this.exchanger = exchanger;
    }

    public void addExchanger(Exchanger exchanger) {
        this.exchanger = exchanger;
    }

    public Exchanger getExchanger() {
        return exchanger;
    }

    public Bus(ArrayList busStations) {
        this.busStations = busStations;
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < busStations.size(); i++) {
            beforeState.doAction(this, busStations.get(i));
            busStations.get(i).addBus(this);
            afterState.doAction(this, busStations.get(i));
            busStations.get(i).getSemaphore().release();
        }
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setPassengers(Passengers passengers) {
        lock.lock();
        if (passengers.getQuantity() < 0) passengers = new Passengers(0);
        try {
            this.passengers = passengers;
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public Passengers getPassengers() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            return passengers;
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

класс `BusStation`:

```
public class BusStation {
    private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(BusStation.class);
    private String name;
    private final int busLimit = 2;
    private Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(busLimit);

    public BusStation(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void addBus(Bus bus) {
        try {
            semaphore.acquire();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            logger.error("Semaphore error", e);
        }
        new InState().doAction(bus, this);
    }
    public Semaphore getSemaphore() {
        return semaphore;
    }
}
```

класс, который отвечает за действия на остановке:

```
public class InState implements IState {
    private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(InState.class);

    @Override
    public void doAction(Bus bus, BusStation busStation) {
        logger.info("Bus number " + bus.getNumber() + " is on the station " + busStation.getName());
        Random rand = new Random();
        if (busStation.getSemaphore().availablePermits() == 0) {
            if (rand.nextInt(10) > 5) {
                try {
                    Passengers tmpPassengers = bus.getPassengers(); //
                    tmpPassengers = (Passengers) bus.getExchanger().exchange(bus.getPassengers()); //  Here programm`s blocking
                    bus.setPassengers(tmpPassengers); //
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    logger.error("Exchanger mistake", e);
                }

            } else bus.setPassengers(new Passengers(bus.getPassengers().getQuantity() - rand.nextInt(10)));
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "In state";
    }
}
```

Comment: Покажите еще `Exchanger `.

Comment: трудно ответить без всех исходников. что происходит в классах BeforeState и AfterState?